# Spark repartition is slow and shuffles too much data

Tags: apache-spark

My cluster:

- 5 data node
- each data node has: 8 CPUs, 45GB memory

Due to some other configuration limit, I can only start 5 executors on each data node. So I did

```
spark-submit --num-executors 30 --executor-memory 2G ...
```

So each executor uses 1 core.

I have two data set, each is about 20 GB. In my code, I did:

```
val rdd1 = sc...cache()
val rdd2 = sc...cache()

val x = rdd1.cartesian(rdd2).repartition(30) map ...
```

In the Spark UI, I saw the `repartition` step took more than 30 mins, and it cause data shuffle of more than 150GB.

I don't think it is right. But I could not figure out what goes wrong...

Comment: Just as an aside, you should always cache after a repartition or else you will end up shuffling on each hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you really mean "cartesian"?

You are multiplying every row in RDD1 by every row in RDD2. So if your rows were 1k each, you had about 20,000 rows per RDD. The cartesian product will return a set with 20,000 x 20,000 or 400 million records. And note that each row would now be double in width -- 2k -- so you'd have 800 GB in RDD3 whereas you only had 20 GB each in RDD1 and RDD2.

Perhaps try:

```
val x = rdd1.union(rdd2).repartition(30) map ...
```

or maybe even:

```
val x = rdd1.zip(rdd2).repartition(30) map ...
```

?

Comment: Incidentally, if your record sizes are more like they are in my world -- 100 bytes or so -- you'd have ten times as many records per file, roughly 200 thousand per file. After the cartesian product you'd have 40 billion records, each 200 bytes, for 8 TB of data.

Comment: Yes, I did mean **catesian**. I know it is gonna grow big, but I did not expect it to be so slow just to do the partition.

Comment: I'd say 30 minutes is actually super fast for this. How fast did you expect and why?